# Disable Button on Edittext's text change in Android

Tags: android

I want to disabled button and not click when textview is empty and enable and get click event fire when text is not empty.

Below is the code used

```
    txtVesselName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_VesselName);
    btnPost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_addPost_Send);

    txtVesselName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    etxtVesselCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_VesselCode);
    etxtVesselCode.addTextChangedListener(vesselWatcher);

 if(txtVesselName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
           // btnPost.setClickable(true);
            btnPost.setEnabled(false);
            btnPost.setClickable(false);
            btnPost.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        }
        if(txtVesselName.getText().toString().trim() != null)
        {
            btnPost.setClickable(true);
            btnPost.setEnabled(true);
        }

btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Click to this", "");
        }
    });
```

when i use `btnPost.setEnabled(false);` button is not disabled & can be clicked in this condition .How can I create such a behaviour.

below is my `AddTextChangeListenerMethod()` method

```
private final TextWatcher vesselWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            txtVesselName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 0)
            {
                txtVesselName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from VesselList where Notation " + "= ? ", new String[]{etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim()});

                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        strVesselsTypeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VesselsTypeName"));
                        Log.e("strVesselsTypeName", "=" + strVesselsTypeName);

                        SharedPreferences sp;
                        sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                        e.putString("xyz",etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim());
                        e.commit();

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }  db.close();

                txtVesselName.setText(strVesselsTypeName);
                btnPost.setEnabled(true);

                Log.e("afterTextChanged"," = "+strVesselsTypeName);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: where is your addTextChangedListener method?

Comment: Thank you for the reply .I have post addTextChangedListener  this method above . Please see.

Answer (score 0):

In afterTextChanged() add

```
btnPost.setClickable(true);
```

after,

```
btnPost.setEnabled(true);
```